# Failure: gem install rbczmq due to autogen error

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, iruby

I am trying to add IRuby kernel into my Jupyter so that I can write notes on Ruby, as I just started learning to solve problems in Ruby. 
On the [IRuby doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/iruby/0.2.9#Required_dependencies), I am supposed to do the following commands:

```
gem install rbczmq
gem install iruby
```

However, when I do `gem install rbczmq` I get permission denied. When I do `sudo gem install rbczmq`, I get the following:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rbczmq:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160623-27886-pogml8.rb extconf.rb
"./autogen.sh"
autogen.sh: error: could not find libtool.  libtool is required to run     autogen.sh.
ZeroMQ autogen failed!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.      You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
    --with-system-libs
    --without-system-libs


extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9     for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-    linux/2.3.0/rbczmq-1.7.9/gem_make.out
```

I would like to know how I can fix this problem and install IRuby to my Jupyter? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, after hours of trial and error, I finally manage to install it.

I used `sudo apt-get install libtool-bin` and then `sudo gem install rbczmq`

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have actually installed libtool-bin and it still does not work.

Comment: Did you also have install libtool? try   `sudo apt-get install libtool autogen autoconf automake`   If you already have those im lost. Also I had problems with rbczmq so in the end I used `ffi-rzmq`

Comment: Thanks again Ricardo. Did what you mentioned and now installed Iruby. But when I type either `iruby` or `iruby notebook`, I get the "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.2.9/lib/iruby/command.rb:78:in ``':No such file or directory - ipython (Errno::ENOENT)" mistake. May I ask if you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I´m not sure, maybe you don´t have the the jupyter bin flies in your PATH?, If you start `jupyter notebook`. Do you see the ruby kernel?